# Битрикс 24 аналитка собственных форм

Tags: битрикс, формы, битрикс24, аналитика

На сайте есть собственные формы, которые через API забрасывают данные в лиды битрикс24, в сервис рассылки и в call трекер. Но теперь еще надо связать поступления с данных форм с аналитикой. Не могу понять, как это сделать?

Вижу, что можно создать формы через конструктор CRM но они нам не подходят. Можно ли их связать как-то между собой форму на сайте и форму из конструктора CRM? Например с формы сайта передавать в скрытом поле ID формы из CRM что бы по ней считалась аналитика...?

Comment: Используете портал облако или коробку?

Comment: @NikolajSarry коробка

Comment: Делайте собственный отчёт и в него тяните данные с сайта. В коробку можно дописать любой код. Штатный функционал тут не сильно поможет, только доработка.